What memory bandwidth utilisation to expect? And why does multi-threading/multi-processing make it worse?
We have C code that loops over large (10M - 1000M) double arrays (32-byte aligned) and aggregates them. The code (below) looks trivial, but is as fast as we could get it. Over 20 other  approaches, from simple to very elaborated - using SIMD, multi-threaded and/or multi-processing - finally lead to a slower execution. Any attempt to outsmart the compiler failed. Our take aways: Trust the compiler! Do not confuse the compiler! We're using latest clang with all relevant compiler-flags on-fire, -O3 etc.
double sum_double(const double *restrict values, const size_t n) {
    double r = 0;
    #pragma omp simd reduction(+:r)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        r += values[i];
    return r;
}

Here's the thing: On a base M2 Mac with 100GB/s Bandwidth, we can reach max. 65GB/s ≙ ±8B 64bit aggregations/sec. For reference, Numpy reaches exactly the same throughput.
Questions:

Why can't we go beyond this 65GB/s threshold?
35GB/s are still left. Is this simply the time equivalent to our processing?

Why does even multi-threading/-processing make it worth?
We expected multi-processing to be at least equivalent to
the single threaded approach. But performance drops down significantly with every
process or thread added?


Any experiences or opinions on that? Or are we doing something wrong? Thx

You might get a slight improvement with two threads but you will totally saturate memory bandwidth. Have you looked at Fastest way to do horizontal add? Which other methods have you tried that came close to your current best solution. Worth also feeding it to the latest Intel ICX compiler and then using VTune to see where it is spending its time.

@MartinBrown I highly doubt Intel tools support the (ARM) Apple M2 CPU ;) ... especially after Apple stopped using Intel CPU on Mac (not a good new for Intel sales). At least, the previous compiler implementation did not (and AFAIK VTune does not support ARM yet either). Also not that the linked question focus on SSE while the OP runs on a CPU architecture with Neon.

You said your array is 32 bit aligned. Did you mean 32 byte?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR5_SDRAM#:~:text=DDR5%20also%20has%20higher%20frequencies,s)%20of%20bandwidth%20per%20DIMM.

@MartinBrown Thanks for the link! I also believe that Apples ARM platform is still "in the making" when it come to CPU bound HPC use cases, e.g. max 128-bit registers. M4 chips, now adapting ARMv9 (SVE) may change this to some extent.

@SimonGoater, Yes, sorry 32 byte

What performance do you get if you run two instances of your program simultaneously?

I'm inclined to think that if you are matching numpy/LApack for performance and bandwidth there may not be much scope for improvement on the current architecture, but sometimes tiny tweaks can prevent pipeline dependency stalls. You have to figure out where the bottleneck(s) are with a profiler to go any faster. It is a  great shame that Intel's VTune tool is only available on their CPU's.

Optimization of the sequential code
This computation is mainly memory-bound on most platforms as long as the operation is properly vectorized and unrolled.
Here #pragma omp simd reduction(+:r) properly vectorize the loop with -fopenmp or -fopenmp-simd (which not mentioned in the question but rather obvious for any OpenMP codes). Here is the resulting ARM assembly loop:
.LBB0_5:
        ldp     q2, q3, [x9, #-16]
        subs    x10, x10, #4
        add     x9, x9, #32
        fadd    v1.2d, v1.2d, v2.2d
        fadd    v0.2d, v0.2d, v3.2d
        b.ne    .LBB0_5

The thing is it is certainly not optimal because of the latency of the fadd instruction which is typically 2-4 cycles (AFAIK 3 cycles on the Apple M1/M2 CPUs), while there are 4 SIMD units that can execute it per cycle. As a result, the code can be latency-bound if it is not already memory-bound. Even worst : SIMD units likely starve waiting for instruction! One reason the compiler do not optimize further the loop is that it is forbidden by the IEEE-754 standard. One way to fix this is to tell OpenMP to use wider SIMD operations using #pragma omp simd reduction(+:r) simdlen(8). Here is the resulting code:
.LBB0_5:
        ldp     q17, q16, [x9, #-64]
        subs    x10, x10, #16
        ldp     q19, q18, [x9, #-32]
        ldp     q20, q21, [x9]
        fadd    v2.2d, v16.2d, v2.2d
        fadd    v0.2d, v17.2d, v0.2d
        ldp     q17, q16, [x9, #32]
        fadd    v1.2d, v19.2d, v1.2d
        fadd    v3.2d, v18.2d, v3.2d
        fadd    v6.2d, v21.2d, v6.2d
        fadd    v4.2d, v20.2d, v4.2d
        add     x9, x9, #128
        fadd    v5.2d, v17.2d, v5.2d
        fadd    v7.2d, v16.2d, v7.2d
        b.ne    .LBB0_5

Now, the CPU can execute more instructions in parallel because they are independent : 4 instructions/cycle and they can also be better pipelined. This should be far from being enough for the code to be memory-bound.
Note that -march=native might help too.

CPU architecture (bottleneck) & Multithreading
On top of that, one code may not saturate memory because saturating DRAM is not so easy for the hardware. This require large buffers and a lot of transistors so to mitigate the huge (and variable) latency of several LPDDR5 DRAMs. Because of that, some CPU architecture cannot saturate the DRAM memory with only one core even with a perfectly optimized code. This is the case on my Intel Skylake CPU where the LFB (Line-Fill Buffers) unit of the CPU is the bottleneck preventing this.
This is not a problem for such a code because it can be parallelized and all cores are often far enough to saturate the DRAM memory. In fact, only few are often enough.

Why does even multi-threading/-processing make it worth?

If the threads are scheduled on efficient cores, they can be significantly slower. You should check performance core are properly used here. If they do not run on the right cores, you need to bind the threads on performance core. This is a common problem on big-little CPUs like the Apple M1/M2 or even Intel Alderlake (less critical). AFAIK, this does not happen by default on M1/M2 "Pro" version.
Besides using too many threads can be detrimental for performance, not only because memory operations often does not perfectly scale, but also because using efficient core can sometimes slow down the code if the scheduling its not well suited for such architecture (AFAIK the default one is not).

Hi Jérôme, thank you very much for your very insightful explanations. -fopenmp-simd flag was already used. I followed your advices, but neither yields a measurable impact on the max. throughput on my M2 Mac basic. I will start x86/x64 testing on ARM/Intel win/linux and M3 Max in the upcoming days and will check and report what are my findings on different platforms.

Ok. Regarding multithreading, this is complicated, but you can try different scheduling like schedule(guided) or schedule(dynamic,65536). This is just for testing purpose! Indeed, dynamic scheduling can make memory-bound code MUCH slower on both server-side CPUs and client-side AMD CPUs (due to NUMA effects). However, this can be better on big-little client CPUs (mainly/only Apple one so far). AFAIK, you can tune the scheduling at runtime using environment variable (better). A better alternative is to do thread binding as stated in the answer. I am curious of the results :) !

For reference:
A purely stack-based aggregation  yields 114 baggs*/sec single threaded and 360 baggs/sec multi-threaded (code below).
Let's assume this is the max. performance we can gain from the CPU. Then we are still factor 10+ away from the 8 baggs/sec we get on a heap/main memory bound aggregation.
Isn't that a prove that only the main memory interaction is slowing things down? Meaning, the 65GB throughput limit on a 100GB M2 chip is more or less the factual limit that can be achieved?
double array[16] = { ... }
#pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum) simdlen(8)
for (int l = 0; l < loops; l++) {
    sum += sum_array_simd(array, 16);
}
...
double sum_array_simd(double *array, size_t size) {
    float64x2_t sum_vec = vld1q_f64(&array[0]);
    for (size_t i = 2; i < size; i += 2) {            
        float64x2_t vec = vld1q_f64(&array[i]);
        sum_vec = vaddq_f64(sum_vec, vec);
    }
    double result[2];
    vst1q_f64(result, sum_vec);
    return result[0] + result[1];
}

*baggs = billion aggregations

This suggests that there might be a divide and conquer approach that could possibly be beneficial if you can restrict the problem to array lengths 2^N. Basically compute the sum of the pairs at x[i] = x[i] +x[i+2^(N-1)] (and vectorised) much like the FFT does so that as the active array length halves in size each time around you get ever more benefit from caching. All calculations will be independent right until the very last step so it should be pipeline friendly.

@MartinBrown How do you conclude that? The OP just iterates on memory once so there is no possible reuse and cache are useless here. I guess the OP also show that the amount of ILP is not an issue here because of the 10x factor with large arrays.

Note that this answer would be better as an update/edit of the question. Also please note that this show that the memory hierarchy is likely a bottleneck indeed but not necessarily the DRAM. For example, the TLB can be (so you should try with huge pages) and I am pretty sure multiple threads can do better than that on large arrays and I am not convinced 1 core can fully saturate alone the DRAM.

Also note that #pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum) simdlen(8) makes no sense on an already manually vectorized code. At best it will unroll the loop further but at worse it can results in a bogus or inefficient code. It is better not to use it here.

@JérômeRichard the #pragma is actually quite useful on my M2, yields factor 1.5x.

@JérômeRichard summing into one variable there is an unavoidable data dependency  - the previous addition must complete before the next one can execute. Summing half the array into the other half indexing upwards and then folding it again into the lower half with the index going downwards you have already preloaded the cache with the right data at the start of the next loop. The benefits should be measurable. The work done is about the same but without any pipeline stalls and with an increasing fraction of it already in L2 cache. Main disadvantage is it gets messy for non powers of 2.

After a deeper analysis, this benchmark is biased. Indeed, Clang perform smart optimisation and see that sum_array_simd(array, 16); is a constant so it can pre-compute it once and then add the same value many times. All values are stored in registers so it does no even read memory in the hot loop (nor even use load instructions). Not surprizing this is significantly faster, but this benchmark measure something completely different from the initial question : it does not even measure the sum of a small array in practice...

Regarding, #pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum) simdlen(8) helps to unroll the loop further the way I shown in my (above) answer (using simdlen(8)). I still think this is a bad idea to use this (especially with simdlen(8) and also especially since the loop is already vectorized and this does not help to vectorize it better) : OpenMP assume the directives are valid and can generate wrong code otherwise (possibly with race condition depending on the platform so it might work in a CPU and fail on another). It simply unroll better the reduction of a precomputed sum that should not even be so.

Thus, you should really check the assembly code so to see if the benchmark make sense (and you should also check results). If you are not familiar with assembly, then you should use micro-benchmark tools avoiding common micro-benchmark pitfalls and please read Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?.

@MartinBrown In this case, the array sum is precomputed so it is not a bottleneck (: . Even if it would not be it would be certainly stored in registers, and even if it would not be, then it would be stored/reload from/to the L1 cache and not the L2 (and the CPU should benefit from store-forwarding here anyway -- especially the Apple M1/M2/M3 CPUs). Instruction latency is hidden thanks to independent loop iterations, pre-computation and loop unrolling, so it is certainly not a problem here.

@JérômeRichard - It seems that memory bandwidth and context switching limitations per Core is the problem why multithreading is always slower (but all cores 100% on fire). I've tested a multi-processing approach (what I do not want for complexity reasons) and the problems are gone and it scales well, so maybe I need to go that route. Again, thx for your great support.

Here are some figures:
Single-threaded SIMD 100M aggregations in  0.086027 sec, 11624 mops/sec
Multi-processing SIMD 100M aggregations in 0.036469 sec, 27420 mops/sec
...again, multi-threading is slowing things down for both scenarios.

This is unexpected. Generally processes add more overheads than threads. The only things I can think of are NUMA effects and a weird scheduler behaviour / bad thread binding. The former can be generally fixed by just doing the first touch on the same threads that read/write data then (threads needs to be bound to core for better performance), and the later can can be fixed by binding threads to cores manually. Analysing/Setting the binding of threads to core is generally critical for performance. Nearly all HPC application does that nowadays (or the underlying middlewares).

People at the great Anandtech benchmarking website reached about 60% of the theoretical bandwidth using multiple threads on the M1 max. They reported a slight improve using E-cores. Using the 2 cluster was critical for saturating the DRAM bandwidth. Using only few P-core results in a pretty good performance already. Be aware that most CPUs often does not reach more than 90% of the theoretical bandwidth for pure reads (often even rather <80% for high-latency DRAM -- though 60% is rather low).

After looking back this answer and the post, I am confused. Are you talking about the biased benchmark or the initial one benchmarking the reduction on DRAM data? Indeed, 27420 mops/sec on double-precision means 219 GB/s which makes no sense on a "M2 Mac with 100GB/s Bandwidth".

Sorry, I upgraded to an M4 max 2 weeks ago. I should have mentioned that.
